# Android layouts I can't position three items correctly in the same line

Tags: android, layout, position

so I have a problem position three items in the same line for my android app. At first let me show you a screenshot of what I have:

[image: Image Problem]

My problem here is that I'd like the two image button to be to the far left and far right of the line and for the Large Text to stay in Center.

I have tried Relative Layout without success, I also tried android:gravity for each item but it doesn't work either.

Here is the XML for my Layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/settings" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have u tried with setting gravity of image button and other views?

Comment: I would try the Relative Layout again if I was you. It was meant for just this kind of situations AFAIK. It can be tricky to use in Eclipse because the UI designer interface is so horrible.

Comment: First, which layout you want to go with? I would suggest you for both.

Comment: I had tried the gravity indeed, and the layout I did not care as long as it's the "best practice" one ;). Thanks to everybody that took time to reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try with this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/settings" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@color/black" 
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should put `layout_width="0dp"` when using `android:layout_weight="1"` (for the TextView)

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly! So all I had to do was to set the weight to 1 for it to work?  Could you please also explain why I should put the layout_width to 0dp?

Comment: when you want the width or height to be controlled by weight its convention to set that value to 0dip and let the weight control the actual value. Although I am pretty sure 0 is just arbitrary here you could put anything but putting 0 makes your intention more clear.